# Having trouble install Python http package

Tags: python, pip

I am trying to install the Python http package into a virtual environment on my Mac so I can run the Simple HTTP Server but pip  complains that it can't import Request from request:

```
% pip install http
...
ImportError: cannot import name 'Request' from 'request' (/Users/me/.virtualenvs/base/lib/python3.7/site-packages/request/__init__.py)
```

I installed the request package initially but that didn't help.  Thinking that perhaps it needed requests instead, I installed that too to no avail.

Here is my virtual environment:

```
Package          Version  
---------------- ---------
certifi          2019.9.11
chardet          3.0.4    
get              2019.4.13
idna             2.8      
pip              19.3     
post             2019.4.13
powerline-status 2.7      
psycopg2-binary  2.8.3    
public           2019.4.13
query-string     2019.4.13
request          2019.4.13
requests         2.22.0   
setuptools       41.1.0   
urllib3          1.25.6   
wheel            0.33.4
```

I'm running Python 3.7.4 inside a virtual environment built from virtualenv 16.6.2. on macOS Mojave.

Comment: From looking on [PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/http/#files), it seems that package hasn't been updated since Feb 11, 2012.  You might consider looking into something that has been updated more recently, such as [requests](https://pypi.org/project/requests/2.7.0/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not have to install anything to run `SimpleHTTPServer`. `http` is in the standard libary.

Also note that `SimpleHTTPServer` is called `http.server` in Python 3.

Comment: Thank you, I'm glad to help :)

Answer (score 0):

upgrade your pip with the below command and try again

```
python -m pip install –upgrade pip
```

If the above fails you can also try an earlier version for which it works

```
pip install --upgrade pip==9.0.3
```

The error could be because in the current pip, you have to pip install requests module first this in not taken care internally as the dependency is removed

Comment: The first thing I did after creating the virtual environment was to upgrade pip so I don't think that's the problem.

Comment: can you try with an earlier version of pip as i have mentioned

Comment: I could but it seems ridiculous to have to downgrade pip in order to install such a commonly-used package.  I'd prefer to understand (if possible) why this doesn't work with the current version of pip.  I'll try it, but I don't think we should have to do this.  But thanks for your suggestion, I'm not killing the messenger.  ;-)   UPDATE: Downgraded to pip 19.0.3 but that didn't help.  UPDATE: Oh geez, this http package is seven years old!  I'm going to look for something newer.